# Do any airports other than Mataveri restrict the number of airplanes that can fly within their sphere of influence at any one time?

Tags: airport-operations

[Mataveri International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataveri_International_Airport) (SCIP), located on Rapa Nui (Easter Island; Isla de Pascua) in far southeastern Polynesia, somewhat famously, bans more than a single airplane from flying within the area of airspace that is closer to Mataveri than to any other airport (what we might call Mataveri’s “sphere of influence”) at any one time.

This is because:

1. Mataveri is the most isolated airport on Earth, such that a smaller airplane could easily find itself near the limits of its endurance if it were to be flown there and then forced to divert.
2. Mataveri has only one runway, meaning that, if said runway were blocked by a crashed or otherwise disabled aircraft, the airport would have to be closed until the runway could be cleared.

My question is: do any airports *other* than Mataveri restrict the number of airplanes that can be within their sphere of influence simultaneously?

Comment: Could you add a reference to the relevant regulation? (Perhaps from the Chilean AIP)

Comment: Also I feel like there should be a better term than "sphere of influence" for this concept - perhaps something related to the idea of Voronoi partitioning

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're thinking of, but in the US there's a ["one in, one out rule"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52195/62) that any towered airport might use depending on operational conditions and needs. There are a lot of possible variables.